# npm cache add <package-name> not adding the package to the cache directory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-cache

I have a project using `<package-name>` package. After installing this package, is it cached automatically? And how can I check if it is cached? (When I navigate to the npm-cache folder, I see no directory named `<package-name>`)
My second question is, when using the command: `npm cache add <package-name>`, and then navigating to the npm-cache directory, again I see nothing about `<package-name>` there. Why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html

> There is currently no method exposed through npm to inspect or
>   directly manage the contents of this cache. In order to access it,
>   cacache must be used directly.

So you'd need to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cacache to inspect the contents directly.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm config` command. You might have changed the `default` paths.

**Command:**
`$ npm run list`

OR

`$ npm run ls -l` # for all

**Look for prefix setting:** `prefix` setting

// Outputs:

```
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.7.0 node/v11.15.0 darwin x64"

; userconfig /Users/xdeepakv/.npmrc
prefix = "/Users/xdeepakv/.npm-global"

; node bin location = /Users/xdeepakv/Softwares/node-v11.15.0-darwin-x64/bin/node
; HOME = /Users/xdeepakv
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

**Note:** You can also check these in `~/.npmrc` **[mac/linux]**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My default paths are correct. Let me ask my question with an example. Suppose I'm using "lodash" in my project. And my OS is windows, we know npm cache directory is at: %AppData%/Roaming/npm-cache. When I use "npm cache add lodash", nothing is added to the "npm-cache" directory. Just some weird data is added to _cacache directory. Where are cached packages saved?